# Could not find azure app service hosted web api in azure api management

Tags: azure-api-management

I have a created a web api with token based authentication and deployed in azure app service. If i try to open from azure hosted app service in APIM it could not find. do we need change settings?(I am not authenticating with azure AD because it is test service).

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in advance,
Eswar

Comment: When you will not get a response from API management you should check HTTPS status code. What status code are you getting?

Azure AD not mandatory with APIM. you can create one hello world api in same application (without any security) then you can try to access that api thro APIM.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/g_arora/Asp-Net-web-api-create-deploy-to-azure-and-manage-using-az/

Comment: I am not calling APIM. I just created normal web API and hosted in Azure app service. when I browse it from API app in APIM. My service is not detected.

Comment: What is status code APIM returning?

Comment: For me it came after some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APIM supports importing only API apps. Try going to https://resources.azure.com/ and locating your app there. In its properties it must have kind equal to "api".

Comment: it is available in resources but not detected in APIM when i browse for it.              
            "id": "/subscriptions/---/resourceGroups/CCS-T/WebAPIDemo17",
      "name": "WebAPIDemo17",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "kind": "app",
      "location": "centralus",
      "identity": {
        "principalId": "",
        "tenantId": "",
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },

Comment: There you go. APIM recognizes only kind=api, not app. But that doesn't matter much. Do you have OpenAPI spec for your app? If so - just import it as a regular API, if not - just register is as regular API.

Comment: I have only url. How to get openApi spec https://firstadwebapp20161103050055.azurewebsites

Comment: Host in Azure api app

Comment: @Eswarreddy OpenAPI spec is something you either write yourself, or is generated for you by something like Swashbuckle: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle/. Either way, if you don't have one you can still register API manually in APIM. Just click "Add API" and select "Blank"

Answer (score 0):

When you import an API App in APIM, APIM finds the swagger associated with the selected app, fetches it, and imports it. In case **APIM does not find swagger, it exposes the API as a "pass-through" API**.

So when you create API app in local, you need to choose `Azure API App` and then deploy to azure. So that, you could find it.

[image]

Comment: Azure API App also not find in APIM